# Tree constrction from csv with labeled edge

Tags: python-3.x, csv, tree, graphviz, anytree

I have a csv file, and want to construct a tree by reading the file contents

```
id  | screen_name |    reply_status_id |      tweet            | stance
1   |      a      |        null        |     dahgfsjhg         |  +
2   |      b      |         1          |     fcjgvujhgjhk      |  -
3   |      c      |         2          |     ououoijoskjfpokpo |  +
4   |      d      |         1          |     giuyhewikuhieuhi  |  +
5   |      e      |         3          |     hkjhkjlkjljlkjlj  |  -
```

I want to create a tree structure based on id and reply_status_id with tweet.

Like,

```
                 a [root]
(stance of b)  -/ \+ (stance of d)
               b   d  [childs]
             +/
             c
           -/
           e
```

My csv file is

```
[link]drive.google.com/open?id=1Z8paHBJVv6FJWeskYyR_6AhB2Ifor4Mz.
```

I have constrcted tree using this code:

```
import csv
from anytree import Node
from anytree.exporter import DotExporter

def find_subnodes(root_node, root_node_id, nodes):
  for row in lst:
    node_id = row[0]
    # name = regex.sub('', row[3])
    name = row[3].replace('\\"', '\'').replace('"', '')
    parent_node_id = row[2]
    if root_node_id == parent_node_id:
        node = Node(name, root_node)
        nodes[node_id] = node
        nodes = find_subnodes(node, node_id, nodes)
return nodes

with open('rumour1.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   next(reader)
   lst = list(reader)
r_node = Node(lst[0][3].replace('\\"', '\'').replace('"', ''))
n = {lst[0][0]: r_node}
n = find_subnodes(r_node, lst[0][0], n)
DotExporter(r_node).to_picture('tree.png')
```

But the edges are not yet marked with this code. Can any one help me to add edges with stance column[last column in csv].

Comment: Can any one please help to solve this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [`column`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html) command (from [util-linux](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux))

```bash
$ cat input.csv
id,screen_name,reply_status_id
1,a,null
2,b,1
3,c,2
4,d,1
5,e,3

$ tail -n+2 input.csv | column -t -s, -i1 -p3 -r2 -H1,3
a
├─b
│ └─c
│   └─e
└─d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps, first to convert the dataframe into a tree structure using parent-children relationship, then print/show out the tree. This can be done in two lines of code using [bigtree](https://bigtree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```py
# Set up (I only took the relevant columns)
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, "a", None, "+"],
    [2, "b", 1, "-"],
    [3, "c", 2, "+"],
    [4, "d", 1, "+"],
    [5, "e", 3, "-"]
], columns=["id", "screen_name", "reply_status_id", "stance"]
)

# Some preprocessing
rename_dict = dict(zip(data["id"], data["screen_name"]))
data["id"] = data["id"].replace(rename_dict)
data["reply_status_id"] = data["reply_status_id"].replace(rename_dict)

# 1. Convert dataframe into a tree structure
from bigtree import dataframe_to_tree_by_relation

node = dataframe_to_tree_by_relation(
    data,
    child_col="id",
    parent_col="reply_status_id",
)

# 2. Print/show the tree
node.show()
```

This will yield the result

```
a
├── b
│   └── c
│       └── e
└── d
```

If you want to show the stance information, you can try exporting it out as an image with the edges labelled with stance information.

```py
from bigtree import tree_to_dot

graph = tree_to_dot(node, edge_attr=lambda x: {"label": x.stance})
graph.write_png("tree_stance.png")
```

[image: tree_stance.png]

Disclaimer: I'm the author of bigtree :)